# How to define lemmatizer function in a for loop to a single print function statement in python

Tags: python, nlp

I need to add the function within the print function to a variable to be calledd to be printed only from the variable name.

My code -
`for w in processed_H2_tag: print(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower(), pos=wordnet.VERB))`

Expected - `Print(output)`

"Output" is to be defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean how to instead of printing get all the values into a list which you can then print?

You can do that with a list comprehension:

```
output = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower(), pos=wordnet.VERB) for w in processed_H2_tag]
```

Or if you prefer a classic for loop:

```
output = []
for w in processed_H2_tag:
    output.append(lemmatizer.lemmatize(w.lower(), pos=wordnet.VERB))
```